# hide and unhide SKSprite Node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am trying to hide a node when it's clicked and unhide it when a button is clicked. After unhiding the node, I can't click it again but I want it to be clickable again. Below is my code for hiding and unhiding using SKAction. Am I missing something?

when the ball Node is clicked it is hidden and added to an array clickedBall

```
ballNode.runAction(SKAction.hide())
clickedBall.append(ballNode)
```

when the button is clicked, it is shown via array clickedBall

```
clickedBall.last?.runAction(SKAction.unhide())
```

but I can't click the node again to hide it again..

please help.. thank you

Answer (score 2):

When the node is clicked, instead of running an action, you can use the node's 'hidden' property:

```
ballNode.hidden = true
```

and then set the value to `false` when you want the node to reappear

Comment: i can still not click it when it reappeared.. :(

Answer (score 1):

When the node is clicked, to hide it you can run `ballNode.removeFromParent()` and to add it back `addChild(ballNode)`